# Bootstrap @grid-float-breakpoint issues in Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, responsive-design, nav

I am working with Bootstrap 3.3.2 . My Goal with the site im building was to have the nav menu always collapsable, like when it is in mobile view. to accomplish this I went to bootstrap.com/customize and changed the `@grid-float-breakpoint:` to `99999999px;` so large that it would never uncollapse the nav. This works fine for all other browsers except for Safari. In safari my nav header image shows up, but the icon for the drop-down menu is gone.

In safari when inspecting the drop-down icon's css I find:

```
    @media (min-width: 99999999px;){ 
    .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
    }
    }
```

It seems as if Safari thinks my viewport is actually greater then 99999999px. Now the simple change would be to adjust my code to `display: inline;` But when i do this it takes the `.navbar-toggle` out of the grid system and not pliable for responsive.

Any help towards a solution or if anyone knows of this as a bug issue, would help out alot. I have already researched issues with the `@grid-float-breakpoint` and did not find much other then this WAS an issue with chrome a while back but has since been patched.

thanks

Comment: Share a fiddle that reproduces your problem. It'll be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're referring to http://crbug.com/375574 , which apparently still applies to Safari 8. The solution is to use a somewhat less absurdly-high value for `@grid-float-breakpoint`. Removing a single digit seems to be sufficient:

```
@media (min-width: 999999999px) {
```

Also, I went ahead and filed a WebKit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141533

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with the css for a few hours I found that adjusting the `@media (min-width: 9999999999px) .nav-bartoggle` to `-webkit-display: inline;` and adjusting the parent element width and a few other adjustments can result in acceptable code. Im sure cvrebert's method will work much better. But I just wanted to comment that there is pure css work arounds in the case some one needs to know in the future.